# getting google maps working on phone/tablet (no problem on emulator)

Tags: android, google-maps, keystore

most people have the opposite problem that I do..  I have no issues on the emulators (API keys should be correct).  But when I take it to my tablet.. I don't get anything..

do the apps needs signed to touch base w/ google maps (when installed on a tablet/phone)?  Getting apps signed has not been working out well for me..  even got an error trying to say my debug.keystore has been manipulated?

If someone has a very nicely laid out walk through for creating the key I would be greatly appreciated.  I've tried this in eclipse and through command prompt.. Nothing but issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you copied your project from some other place. Try to go through the directory of your project and delete anything that you don't think should be in there. Delete any generated files or keystores you find in there. Rename the package to your own package name, please do not pick com.android. And then, rebuild everything.

Or better yet, create an android project from scratch, and put in the minimum code that will render a map, and then test it on a phone to see if you get the same result.

And then, test it on the tablet after that (you say it hasn't worked on the tablet, but I remain unclear as to whether you tested it on a phone too).

And do not sign anything, just connect it to your tablet with the usb cable, set your tablet to debug mode, and select run as an android application (Eclipse will do the rest with the debug.keystore and the signing).

And by the way, starting in Android 2.2 or 2.3, the google map API keys don't need to be correct anymore to work on the emulator I believe. The complaints you found probably predate this change.

Comment: if it works on an emulator then the debug key should be ok, it still could be that 1. the device u are using doesn't even have maps or the device doesn't accept for some reason debug certificates and then you need to do 2 things:1. create your own key and get it's foot print. 2. create maps API key from that footprint. 3. change the MapView key to the one you got. 4. export your project as a sign application with your key.

Comment: it ended up just being a mess w/ my API keys.. I finally have them organized properly..  had created keys and debug keys for numerous locations all jumbled around..